# Using a method to get multiple, random strings to show as text in an XML

Tags: android, xml, text, formatting

I have a list of about 10 strings that all have different sayings (adages).  How can I go about randomly displaying them for the user to read on an XML?

I have a math().random; that generates a random # between 1 and 10.  When that number is hit, I use a simple switch/case that displays a saying to the user in an xml file.  How do I go about displaying that predefined string in the xml?

ie:

```
private void randomIdioms(){
int saying = math.random()*10;

if (saying = 3){
 //THe code I am looking for that displays a string on a view in the XML file

}else if (saying = 2){
}
```

etc....

Thanks!

Comment: this might just be a copy error on your part but if you use if(saying = 3) your assigning 3 to saying and it always return true, you want to do if(saying == 3)

Comment: How do you create the XML? You aren't very clear about what you are trying to do. Also, why are you using a switch? Won't an array of sayings do?

Comment: I am not sure - how do I make an array of sayings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by display in a xml

but I would recommend this

1)store all your Idioms in a List or array list

2) shuffle it

http://www.java-examples.com/shuffle-elements-java-arraylist-example

3) display the n first ones you want to show.

### Edit:

now I re read your question it occurs that your maybe waiting to display just 1 string. in that case

1)store your idioms in a `tab[]` or `arrayList`

2)do a `index = Math.radom()*sizeOfCollection;`

(sorry about that)

---

regarding the display I still don't get the xml part

say you have in your view a TextView in your xml layout, then what you want to do is

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_textView);
if(myTextView != null){
   myTextView.setTextView(myTextIdiom);
}
```

you can look at [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) for layout and changing layout content

hope it helps

jason

Comment: Hey - thanks!Sorry about that being unclear.  I created 10 strings in my string.xml file, all with different sayings as values.  All I was looking to do was have the app randomly generate a number, and have that number display a saying (in a text View - if that's what I need to do) to the user on the screen. ;)

Comment: read this blog I think it might help you http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/49733.aspx